# NSAttributedString with link

Tags: objective-c, nsattributedstring

I have string with 2 words. I want to color 2 words with different colors say red and green.
Also it the whole string should have clickable link. I tried with following code, the link attribute overrides the previous colors.

```
NSString *str = @"xxxx yyyyyy"; 

NSMutableAttributedString *attStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:str];
[attStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                   value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, 4)];
[attStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                   value:[UIColor blueColor] range:NSMakeRange(5, str.length-5)];

NSMutableAttributedString *clickStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]  initWithAttributedString:attStr];

    [clickStr addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:@"textLink:link" range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];
```

Comment: What is it about a link that you want to display? Certainly not the text color, right? The underlining? You can simply add that as another attribute to the whole range of the string.

Comment: I want to preserve the text color that i added before link attribute. I am not concerned about underline.

Comment: That's what I'm asking, though--if you want the red and blue colors, then what is it about a link that you want to add to the string?

Comment: red and green color is overridden by blue which comes from the link. I don't want blue color for whole string but want to maintain previous colors.

Comment: For the third time--what attributes of a link do you want to appear, if not the blue color? In other words, why even add the link attributes?

Comment: I want the word to be clickable thats only reason to add link attribute.

Comment: Oh, FFS--then just use a `UIButton` and set the `setAttributedTitle:forState:` to be the red & blue string that you created above.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't override the link style in a default attributed string. You'll have to use something like [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel/) though it does have some bugs on iOS 8 still.